# Replacing multiple sequences in a column by sampling from another source

Tags: r, replace, sample, recode

I have data that has multiple sequences that I'd like to replace by sampling from another data frame. In my head, it would work something like

```
x = seq(1,100, 0.5)
sample_set = rnorm(20,1,1)

# here I want to replace certain values in x and replace them with values sampled from the normal distribution 

x[c(2:5,30:32,50:56),1] = sample(sample_set, length([c(2:5,30:32,50:56)]), replace = TRUE)
```

In my data, this replacement only works for the first sequence specified in

```
x[c(2:5,30:32,50:56),1] # i.e. items 2:5
```

I've explored recode() and several other options, but nothing has completed the replacement at all locations. Thanks in advance! I'm probably overthinking this...

Comment: Yes, good find. It's fixed in the posting now

Comment: Also, `length(dat[c(2:5,30:32,50:56),1])` should be `x` instead of `dat`, and x is a vector, not a data.frame, so you should remove the `,1` (also on the left-hand side). When you do all that, works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have some inconsistencies in the way you refer to x. First you declare it as a one-dimensional object and then you refer to it as a matrix. I believe if you fix that and remove the `dat` from inside the sample function, everything works as you described:

```
x[c(2:5,30:32,50:56)] = sample(sample_set, length(c(2:5,30:32,50:56)), replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting, I was trying to simplify from my data but did so poorly.